# 504 Gateway Time-out Error on PHP Script

Tags: php, timeout, http-status-code-504

I coded a script for database import, it makes a few jobs on database. When I work this script, after a few minutes I'm getting "504 Gateway Timeout Error".

I increased all timeout values on php.ini, also I increased execution times but it is still same.

Answer (score 7):

You can increase maximum execution time in php.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Comment: hi thanks for this. I am making a call to a stripe API and it takes more than around 5 seconds and so I am getting a "gateway timeout" error.. can you tell me where do I put this code in my script? thanks

Comment: increased nothing happened to me.

Answer (score 5):

Write an info file on your server containing

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

View the file in your browser and check the `max_execution_time`

[image: check max whats comes here]

If it's `0` then there is something different to do else make sure you changed on correct ini file.

You can also check your ini file location

[image]

If you still can't fix it please reply :)