# how to deal with long task on laravel to avoid 504 error?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to do a long task (upload file or foreach 100k rows query) but every time I get the 504 error.

I have set `nginx.conf`, `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` and the `set_time_limit(0)` but nothing seems to work.

What is the proper way to deal with long tasks, I mean, is there a way to send responses while doing the job? so the server and client keep communicating? so both parties know that the job isn't done yet?

For example, I know the query have 100k rows, so I know is a long job. Or uploading a large file, I send chunks of it, knowing theres a lot of chunks, but keep getting the 504 error.

Should I send responses for each loop? How can I do that? returning responses ends the job, so I don't know how to keep the task alive

Comment: Does this answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561625/504-gateway-time-out-error-on-php-script

Comment: nope, done that as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [504 Gateway Time-out Error on PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561625/504-gateway-time-out-error-on-php-script)

Comment: nope, done that as well

Comment: I had a similar issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360922/increase-php-fpm-idle-timeout-setting maybe that will help

Comment: you are in LARAVEL and u have great queue system in PHP why not use that? more info https://laravel.com/docs/queues

Comment: I assume, the 100k rows file is on the client, and you want to upload it to the server to e.g. import it in a database? Or is the file already on the server?